# @Async and task:annotation-driven don't work

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I would make new thread that will work in the background. I'm trying use @Async and task:annotation-driven but application don't work.

root-context.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.cebul.jez.model, com.cebul.jez.service, com.cebul.jez.useful, com.cebul.jez.flows, com.cebul.jez.asynch" />

<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler" />
```

AsyncWorker.java

```
@Service
public class AsyncWorker {

    @Async
    public void work() {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("   " + threadName + "  work");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(30000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
    }
    public void cancel() { Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); }
}
```

In controller, I use it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home"})
    public String home(Model model, HttpSession session){


        asyncWorker.work();

            //other code
}
```

If I try run it, I have exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cebul.jez.asynch.AsyncWorker com.cebul.jez.controllers.HomeController.asyncWorker; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.cebul.jez.asynch.AsyncWorker] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.cebul.jez.asynch.AsyncWorker] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 36 more
2014-03-19 13:02:05 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /jez threw load() exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.cebul.jez.asynch.AsyncWorker] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1628)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

If I delete annotation-driven code complie and run, but AsyncWorker task BLOCK application, so AsyncWorker task doesn't run asynchronously.

Could you show me where is the problem ?

Comment: Do your `AsyncWorker` implement any interfaces? How do you inject it into your controller?

Comment: I inject it like this: @Autowired
 private AsyncWorker asyncWorker;

Comment: I tried: public class AsyncWorker implements Worker, where Worker: public interface Worker{
    public void work();
    public void cancel();
}

Comment: What's the package for your worker class? This error has nothing to do with async operations and is a standard bean-resolution issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, your `AsyncWorker` implements an interface.

`@Async` aspect has the same limitations as other Spring aspects, such as `@Transactional`. By default, if you apply it to a class that implements an interface, AOP proxy generated by Spring will implement that interface, but won't extend the class itself, so that it cannot be injected into a field of type `AsyncWorker`.

You have two options:

- Use interface when injecting:

  ```
  @Autowired private Worker asyncWorker
  ```
- Use `proxy-target-class`:

  ```
  <task:annotation-driven 
       executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler" 
       proxy-target-class="true"/>
  ```